# H264 Hardware accelerator element to use in gstreamer for NEXUS 10

Tags: android, gstreamer, nexus-10

I'm trying to decode my video using hardware accelerator of NEXUS 10, OMX.Exynos.AVC.Decoder using gstreamer. My pipeline looks like

gst-launch 0.10 udpsrc  port=5000  caps = \"application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, sprop-parameter-sets=\\"Z0LAH9oBQBbsBEAAAAMAQAAADIPGjag\\=\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\\", payload=96, ssrc=3462890862, clock-base=501705596, seqnum-base=40332\" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! amcviddec-omxexynosavcdecoder !  eglglessink sync=false

but I get the error saying there is no gst element amcviddec-omxexynosavcdecoder

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this issue or do I need to use different element to use HW accelerator.

thanks